# listgrid smartgwt select deselect feature

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

I use SmartGwt Listgrid to show a list of objects, each object contains many subobjects. So when I click on a specific row, I show a popup that allows me to update this subobject's list.

The second constraint is to allow the user to select many rows, to be merged into one row. For that I use checkbox selection type like the following code :

```
myListGrid.setSelectionType(SelectionStyle.SIMPLE);
myListGrid.setSelectionAppearance(SelectionAppearance.CHECKBOX);
```

All work perfectly for the first load. The problem is when I show / hide the popup, the select/deselect feature of the Listgrid stops functioning. Once the checkbox is clicked, it remains unchanged.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: You've mentioned that you're using a popup. Can you tell me which widget are you using as popup? Can you provide a stand-alone code that represents your problem? If not, can you provide some more code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

I answering my own question,
After many hours of investigation, the problem is that I mix listGrid of smartGwt and dialogBog of GWT, when I changed DialogBox with Dialog of smartGwt the problem is solved